# A CDF related inequality

Tags: probability, analysis, inequality

Suppose $F$ and $G$ are two cdf over $[0, 1]$. Let $$z \equiv \frac{\int_{0}^1 x (1 - G(x)) \mathrm{d}F(x)}{\int_{0}^1 (1 - G(x)) \mathrm{d}F(x) }.$$

Does the following inequality hold: $$ \int_z^1 (y - z) \mathrm{d}G(y) \geq \int_0^1 \int_x^1 (y - x) \mathrm{d} G(y) \mathrm{d} F(x) \,\, ?$$ If we define function $r(x) \equiv \int_x^1 (y - x) \mathrm{d} G(y)$, the desired inequality can be stated as $r(z) \geq \int_0^1 r(x) \mathrm{d} F(x)$. Although I know that $r$ is decreasing and convex, but yet have no idea how to proceed. Thank you very much!